# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the exact value of$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1}$$
if it exists?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Why shouldn't the exact value exist?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(2%5En-1)%5E-1+from+1+to+infty

It's about 1.6067, no exact value

Answer (score 0):

Hint.
$$
\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{1}{1-2^{-n}}=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{kn}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{kn}}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{kn}}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{f(m)}{2^m},
$$
where $f(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$.

Comment: that's not really much simpler than the original series...